# What does the second specified button in a MsgBox do?

Tags: vba, excel

I was reviewing a code example on Chandoo's excellent website when I came across this in his [post about using SQL in Excel](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/):

```
MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
```

I've never seen the messagebox with two button options specified. I've been playing around with it, but do not understand what the `+ vbOKOnly` is good for. It seems to make no difference whether it is there or not.

Can anyone tell me what having two button types specified like this is good for or why it was used in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MsgBox` command can be used to display a variety of different messages including (but not limited to) the following types: yes / no, ok, retry, etc.

So, the `MsgBox` can be customized to some degree. In order to allow for that Microsoft is using a binary encoding [as outlined on their website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx).

The essence is that you can display (as shown in your sample code) a critical error message with merely one `OK` button to confirm this. In order to achieve this you can add all of the options you want the message to include.

As shown [on Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx) the option for a critical message box is 16 while the option to include only an `OK` button is 0. Since, 16 + 0 = 16 you are right and there is no difference between the two. The reason is that - by default - any message box comes with an `OK` button only. Therefore it was assigned the 0 value. Yet, if you want your message box to come with an `OK` button and a `Cancel` button then the value would be 1 and the options would accumulate to 16 + 1 = 17 or `vbOKCancel + vbCritical` (both of which should work).

```
MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
```

or

```
MsgBox "I was not able to find any unique Products.", 17
```

Then you'd get a critical error with two buttons instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This helps!

Answer (score 1):

vbCritical refers to the icon shown on the msgbox while vbOKOnly refers to only showing the OK button option.

See here for some examples: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-msgbox/

and even more here: http://analysistabs.com/vba/msgbox-examples-macros/#bm7

Comment: Although I just noticed that vbCritical will have a single OK button as default. Guess Chandoo is not leaving anything to chance.

Comment: Thank you for the useful links on the topic! I couldn't find anything on google myself... probably due to wrong keywords.